# What is the correct connection string for SQLDriverConnect function to connect to cataloged Db2 database with SSL?

Tags: ssl, db2, odbc

What is the correct connection string for SQLDriverConnect function to connect to cataloged Db2 database with SSL? Programming language - C++.

How I prepare database

```
db2 "CREATE DATABASE TESTDB"
....
db2 "CATALOG TCPIP NODE SSLNODE REMOTE <HOST> SERVER <PORT> SECURITY SSL
db2 "CATALOG DATABASE TESTDB AS SSLDS AT NODE SSLNODE"
db2 "TERMINATE"
db2stop
db2start
```

I can connect if using database name "TESTDB", but when using database alias "SSLDS", connection fails:

First connection attempt to cataloged database by alias "SSLDS" shows error

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1224N  The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress, or has terminated the specified request because of an error or a forced interrupt.  SQLSTATE=55032
```

Next connections attempts show error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30040N  Execution failed because of unavailable resources that will not affect the successful execution of subsequent commands and SQL statements:  Reason "0x0", Type of Resource "MEMORY", Resource Name "", Product ID "SQL11013 ".  SQLSTATE=57012
```

Connection string that I used:

```
Database=SSLDS;UID=<USER>;PWD=<PWD>;Protocol=TCPIP;Servicename=<PORT>;Security=SSL;SSLClientKeystoredb=c:\ssl\storage.kdb;SSLClientKeystash=c:\ssl\storage.sth;
```

Db2 instance SSL configuration:

```
SSL server keydb file                   (SSL_SVR_KEYDB) = C:\ssl\server.kdb
SSL server stash file                   (SSL_SVR_STASH) = C:\ssl\server.sth
SSL server certificate label            (SSL_SVR_LABEL) = selfsignedcert
SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) = db2c_DB2
SSL cipher specs                      (SSL_CIPHERSPECS) =
SSL versions                             (SSL_VERSIONS) =
SSL client keydb file                  (SSL_CLNT_KEYDB) =
SSL client stash file                  (SSL_CLNT_STASH) =
```

db2set

```
DB2INSTOWNER=*****
DB2PORTRANGE=***:***
DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=LOCAL,TOKENLOCAL
DB2INSTPROF=C:\PROGRAMDATA\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1
DB2COMM=SSL
```

Create GSK storages

```
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -keydb -create -db "C:\ssl\server.kdb" -stash -genpw
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -keydb -create -db "C:\ssl\storage.kdb" -stash -genpw
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -create -db "C:\ssl\server.kdb" -stashed -label "selfsignedcert" -dn "CN=TestCompany"
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -extract -db "C:\ssl\server.kdb" -stashed -label "selfsignedcert" -target "C:\ssl\server_cert.arm" -format ascii
gsk8capicmd_64.exe -cert -add -db "C:\ssl\storage.kdb" -stashed -label "selfsignedcert" -file "C:\ssl\server_cert.arm" -format ascii
```

Comment: Which programming language calls SQLDriverConnect() ?  What does "connection fails" mean, edit your question to give the __exact__ error code and error message.  How have you defined the __alias__ , i.e. is it in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file and/or `db2cli.ini` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `DATABASE=...` in the connection string, the you must use a real database name , not an alias.

If you want to use an alias , then instead use `DSN=...` (and omit `DATABASE=...`).

Additionally, your connection string should contain `HOSTNAME=...` for best results.

Note also that if you only have a single certificate file then you can avoid the bother of creating a dedicated keystore on the client side by simply using the `SSLServerCertificate=...` keyword with a value being the fully qualified pathname to the certificate file.

Additionally, to externalise all the connection attributes from your `C++` source code, you could simply use `DSN=...;UID=...;PWD=...;`  and define the DSN attributes (including SSL attributes) in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` xml file. Your choice.

Your other errors such as the SQL1224N and SQL30040N are configuration specific, and your question omits the facts of your client and server configs. But fix the connection string first and these errors may disappear.

Comment: You are right, I used wrong CLI keyword "DATABASE" instead "DSN". In my case working connection string is:

`DSN=...;UID=...;PWD=...;Security=ssl;SSLServerCertificate=<path>`

Just a note, if I use SSLClientKeystoredb and SSLClientKeystash keywords, connections fails with error

`[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "SSL". ... .  Communication function detecting the error: "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".  Protocol specific error code(s): "414", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001`

Comment: Consider accepting the answer. The GSKit error code 414 means bad certificate, usually a configuration error , but that is a separate question.